# An easy way to extend java syntax

Tags: java, preprocessor

I want to make some changes in java syntax. **For example** I want to use operator '+' to add vectors. So I want this code:

```
public class Vector2 {
    public float x, y;
    public Vector2(float x, float y) {this.x = x;this.y = y;}
    public String toString() {...}

    public static Vector2 operator+(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) {
        return new Vector2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector2 a = new Vector2(3, 6);
        Vector2 b = new Vector2(2, 8);
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}
```

will be transleted into this standart java-code:

```
public class Vector2 {
    public float x, y;
    public Vector2(float x, float y) {this.x = x;this.y = y;}
    public String toString() {...}

    public static Vector2 operator_plus(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) {
        return new Vector2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector2 a = new Vector2(3, 6);
        Vector2 b = new Vector2(2, 8);
        System.out.println(Vector2.operator_plus(a, b));
    }
}
```

Is there some good and safe way to extend java syntax easier as writing an own compiler?

(I mean not only operator overloading, but essentially a good way to extend java syntax.)

Comment: I think Scala lets you do that.

Comment: if you want to extend the java syntax i guess you will need to write your own compiler

Comment: @Thilo yes, but i want to make some minor changes in java-syntax, not completly change the programming language.

Comment: How do you want to compile the code from some IDE or manually?

Answer (score 6):

Since Java does not support operator overloading, if you really really want that syntax you will need to change languages.

Comment: My question is not about operator overloading at all. It's only an example.

Comment: @AvrDragon, what you really want then?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov some easy and generic way to extend java syntax. Operator overloading is nice feature, but it is only an example.

Comment: If you want to change the syntax, you'll need to change languages.  Otherwise you're not writing Java, because its syntax and language is codified.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the source codes of [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) for inspiration. They do some pretty cool transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You talking about preprocessor. Fast answer is No - java doesn't have possibility to extend language.
But I suggest you to look at [MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/) - this is tool for creating translators and DSL's. But it contains some examples of extending java language([video](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/demos/new_statement/index.html)).
Also one of the main benefits of MPS is that it have plugin for IntelliJ IDEA - so you can easily attach created extensions to this IDE and use them as syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

It will really depends on the type of extensions you want to do. If you want extension that are typical of an functional language, you may use [scala](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/01/why-scala) that combine both OOP and functional paradigms. Maybe your extension can be solve combining [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj.html) and annotations. In the last resource you can use an pre-compiler, but if you think that your extensions are little bite off of whats it is the purpose of Java you may consider to use the another language that best fits your current needs.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this way:

1. write your own or get a preprocessor which would make simple
2. substitutions  create a script which would call preprocessor to
   create temporary files
3. build those temporary files with java compiler

Answer (score 0):

If you can stay within the java grammar, you can create **annotation processors** (javac plugins) to do what you want. An annotation processor is basically java code run at compile time. (Note that annotation processors does *not* need to have anything to do with annotations)

Using a few hacks (basically casts) in your code for your annotation processor, you can get access to javac's internal AST - this includes rewriting the AST during compile time!

A good introduction: [The Hacker's Guide to Javac](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Erni08b.pdf)

All a user has to do to use your plugin is to include your .jar on the classpath when compiling with javac, so it is very easy to use. (You probably want to do IDE plugins too)

This is what the "[Java-OO](https://amelentev.github.io/java-oo/)" javac-plugin does to add operator overloading to Java (operator overloading doesn't require any grammar changes, so it works fine with annotation processors). It is what the popular [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) does as well.

---

The hacks needed to get access to the internals of javac are however "undocumented/unsupported", so there is always the danger that they stop working on new releases of javac.